# Best approach for extensible return object in python

Tags: python

I'm not that familiar with python, so I would like some advice on the best approach for the following situation:

I have created a function analyzing logs and returning tuples like this (example code):

```
def analyse(log):
    # do magic
    return (list_of_timestamps, list_of_values)
```

Usage:

```
log = import_my_log()
timestamps, data = analyse(log)
if timestamps:
    plot(log)
```

Than we needed plots of other data, so we extended analyse():

```
def analyse(log):
    # do magic
    return (list_of_timestamps, list_of_values, list_of_other_values)
```

so we needed to change the line `timestamps, data = analyse(log)` to `timestamps, data, other_data = analyse(log)`, because it changes the interface. I C-Code, I would return a struct and access like `mydata.timestamps`. My only solution seems to create a class `myData` with members, which I would return and access like the C-Struct.

Is there a better/more pythonic way?

Comment: What's *un*-pythonic about using a class? The more object-oriented you go, the smoother your data analysis, in my experience. Use your `log` variable as the argument to the *constructor* of an analysis object, wherein you attach the processed data as attributes of `self`. The added advantage is that you can implement other methods like `.plot()` or `.save()` that can be called effortlessly (and hence without human error) for that analysis instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a dictionary:

```
return {'timestamps': list_of_timestamps, 'values': list_of_values}
```

If you need to later add things, you just add more keys:

```
return {'timestamps': list_of_timestamps, 'values': list_of_values, 'avg_coffee_consumption': 12e9}
```

With dicts, you get the values back via indexing with the keys, i.e.:

```
result = analyse(log)
v = result['values']
```

You can also actually use your `struct` approach; now, Python `object`s are run-time extendable, so your `analyze` might contain

```
class return_t:
  pass
def analyze(log):
  ret_val = return_t()
  ret_val.values = list_of_values
  ret_val.timestamps = list_of_timestamps
  ret_val.avg_coffee_consumption = 12e9
  return ret_val
...
result = analyze(l)
coffee_used = ret_val.avg_coffee_consumptions * (max(ret_val.timestamps) - min(ret_val.timestamps))
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a dict:

```
def analyse(log):
    # do magic
    return {'timestamps':list_of_timestamps, 'values': list_of_values}
```

Or create a class:

```
class MeasureItem():
    def __init__(self, timestamp, value)
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.value = value

def analyse(log):
        # do magic
        return MeasureItem(timestamp, value)
```